# Split PDF into multiple files based on QR code

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js

I have a scanned pdf which consists of combined answer scripts of students for given exam. In the last page of every student's answer script, they will be a qrcode which uniquely identifies the student.

How to split the pdf based on qrcode & save each answer script as separate pdf?

Comment: Is this tagged vue.js on purpose, or will a mix of bash and python be good enough?

Comment: we can use either vue.js or python

Comment: there is a module called split_qr_exam in python...Have no clarity on the options mentioned in usage of documenatation

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use PyPDF2 library for your usecase ,the documentation is available here . [Link](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/)